# List files appended with an order number

Tags: bash, ls

Is there a quick way to list all the files from a location having an appended order number?

something like:

```
ls -a
```

generates the result:

1 file a

2 file b

...

100 file whatever

Thanks.

P.S. I need this because I am exporting a list to a file, and I have to analyse those files, and it would help me to be able to identify the files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the terminal use the following command:

```
ls -a | cat -b
```

Comment: @bioShark, Remember to accept the answer if it solved the problem (clicking on the check mark next to the answer).

Comment: @edwin I wanted to accept the answer right away, but it told me I need to wait 3 more minutes :). I am not new to askubuntu, so I know that I have to accept the answers.

Comment: Bonus point from me if you make cat -b zfill so sorting works.

Answer (score 6):

yes there is. just pipe `nl` to the end of the your command:

In this case you should write in this way:

```
ls -a | nl
```

and the result is :

1. foo
2. bar
3. baz

`nl` refers  to number line of files.

also look at here :) http://www.sitepoint.com/15-little-known-unix-commands/?

Comment: Thanks. This is the most straight forward answer. However I will not change the accepted answer, because it would be unfair. I have solved my problem with the help of karel's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Karel's answer is fine for most cases but it will break in the unlikely case where your file names contain  newlines. For a more robust approach use `stat` instead:

```
stat --printf "%N\n" * | cat -n
```

or find`and a`while` loop:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '"%f"\0' | 
while IFS=$'\0' read -r -d $'\0' file; do 
  let c++; printf "%d\t%s\n" $c "$file"; 
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Great solutions, both of them. However for my simple need, it's a bit overkill :)